# What is the word being used here?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm having trouble identifying a spoken word from a video.  The word sounds like "sarathically", but no such work exists.

In [the youtube video *Jonathon Miller as Bertrand Russell*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSifxC_L9F0),  Russell says of Moore,

> "No", he replied, and smiled *sarathically*, as was his wont.

The sentence is uttered starting at about 56 seconds.

**Q :** What is the word being uttered?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [transcription request](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10723/191178).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **seraphic** adj
>   Characteristic of or resembling a seraph.
>   *a seraphic smile*
>
> **seraphically** adv
>
> **seraph** n
>   An angelic being

New Oxford American Dictionary